# Execution of dynamodb queries in threading.Thread does not work in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, amazon-dynamodb

[Environment]
Python: 3.9.12
botocore: 1.29.136
running on AWS
architecture: AWS lambda
deployed using serverless framework

I have a heavy job which takes a while.
So I decided to return a success code to a client that requests the job right after receiving the requests and then complete it using thread.
But it does not work without telling any specific exceptions and explanations.
When I change it to just a single thread, it works fine.
I think I'm missing something here.

My code looks like the below.
When a request is received from a client, delete_all_data is called.

[Does not work]
function delete_devices is called, but it seems to be stuck there.

```
def delete_all_data(self, request_data):
    # some codes here..
    # devices_to_delete is gotten from query
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.delete_all, args=(request_data['key1'], devices_to_delete,))
    # some codes here..
    thread.start()

    return SUCCESS

def delete_all(self, owner, devices):
    # some codes here..
    self.delete_devices(devices)
    # some codes here..

def delete_devices(self, devices):
    # _device is dynamodb table object gotten from boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('device_tbl')
    try:
       for item in devices:
           self._device.delete_item(Key={'device_key': item['device_key']})
    # some codes here..
```

[Work well]

```
def delete_all_data(self, request_data):
    # some codes here..
    # devices_to_delete is gotten from query
    self.delete_devices(devices_to_delete)
    
    # some codes here..
    return SUCCESS


def delete_devices(self, devices):
    try:
       for item in devices:
           self._device.delete_item(Key={'device_key': item['device_key']})
    # some codes here..
```

Comment: did you try to use `logging` to debug code - to write information which line of code was executed and what was in variables? Or maybe `AWS lambda` has restrictions for multithreading?

Comment: If you're returning the status code, AWS Lambda is probably pausing the execution. You could confirm if this is the case by blocking until the thread is complete, then returning the success code. If your DDB code works then, it would confirm the issue is because your process is being paused after you send the response.

Assuming that that is the problem, I'd suggest you instead queue up the batch, then use another lambda to perform the bulk operations. This allows you to spread the work out and return a faster response.